# Confusion with Constructor chaining

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to understand few constructor chaining, I know that Calling a constructor from the another constructor of same class is known as Constructor chaining,

When we use this inside a constructer, we are actually calling another constructor that we already have defined, but the program that I am trying to understand is weird,

```
public AESCipher(Key key) {
        this(key.getEncoded());
    }

    /**
     * Create AESCipher based on existing {@link Key} and Initial Vector (iv) in bytes
     *
     * @param key Key
     */
    public AESCipher(Key key, byte[] iv) {
        this(key.getEncoded(), iv);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Create AESCipher using a byte[] array as a key</p>
     * <p/>
     * <p><strong>NOTE:</strong> Uses an Initial Vector of 16 0x0 bytes. This should not be used to create strong security.</p>
     *
     * @param key Key
     */
    public AESCipher(byte[] key) {
        this(key, INITIAL_IV);
    }

    private AESCipher(byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        try {
            this.secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            this.iv = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_AES256);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
    }
```

In the first constructor, this line is used `this(key.getEncoded())`, which constructor is this line calling ? there is no constructor before it in fact there is no constructor with one parameter.

and in the 3rd constructor, there is just one argument of type `byte[]`, and this is what happening inside is,

```
this(key, INITIAL_IV);
```

it is chaining a constructor with two parameters, one of type `key` and of of type `byte[]`, so it is chaining this constructor `AESCipher(Key key, byte[] iv)`, this is fine, but still...what is happening in the first constructor , and why there is a need of 4 constructors at first place.

P.S: I just didn't post this question, I have spent like 4hours trying to understand what is happening but its too confusing.

Here is the complete code,

https://github.com/mike-ensor/aes-256-encryption-utility/blob/master/src/main/java/com/acquitygroup/encryption/AESCipher.java

Comment: [Key#getEncoded()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded%28%29). `in fact there is no constructor with one parameter.` Sure? I can see two constructors with one argument.

Comment: I am guessing `Key#getencoded()` returns a `byte[]`. So, `this(key.getencoded())` is calling the third constructor in the code you show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first constructor is calling the third constructor: `public AESCipher(byte[] key)`.

As far as why there are 4 constructors in the first place, it's intended to encapsulate the logic that deals with turning a `Key` into a `byte[]`, and to allow for the user to use a different initial vector if they so choose.

Comment: is spot on.  Additionally I noticed this: ` there is no constructor before it ...`.  If by this you are under the impression that you cannot call to methods further in the file; nothing can be farther from the truth.  Java is unconcerned with the order that methods, or other bits, appear in the file (for the most part...static initialization rules do care, but that's not the issue here).